# VSTS Build is failing with Polymer build

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am running npm,lerna,yarn and bootstrap in my VSTS build definitions via Command line task after running all the above commands I am running npm run build command but while running npm run build command its failing with 'polymer' is not recognized as an internal or external command.Please help me on this.I tried running polymer in a command line passing polymer as a tool and arguments as build even though its failing.Please help me.

Comment: You have to provide more details for this question. Can you share the logs from the Command line task? Do you have any other tasks before it that install tools? What is this Polymer command line tool? Is it an NPM package? Also are you running on your own agent or using one of the hosted agents? If you are using your own agent what is installed? If you are using a hosted agent which one?

Comment: @SanderAernouts, I tried running the npm run build command from command line task in VSTS build definition using hosted agent  but its failing with polymer so tried another way to run polymer using command line task only running polymer command under tool and passing argument as build still its failing.I have attached the both the logs @ https://1drv.ms/f/s!AvMxvVJdKJlViDCROO-7z_AhfO4T . Please check and let me know.

Comment: @SanderAernouts I am running using a hosted agent VS 2017 and hosted agent and polymer is a command in package.json file and its a npm task or UI task.

Comment: @PDBR Can you share the latest build logs in one drive?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT,Please find the latest logs @ https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvMxvVJdKJlViDEuWCmcqIx8xn5z and give me the solution.

Comment: @PDBR What if you use `polymer build` instead of `npm run build` in VSTS build definition? Besides, can you also share your project (or a sample project with same build error) in one drive?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT,I tried running the polymer build command still the issue persists.I have shared the latest log @ https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvMxvVJdKJlViDJZIvyTkLwAIAeP

Comment: @PDBR Can you share your project in one drive? Or at least `package.json` is necessary.

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT, Please find the package.json  @ https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvMxvVJdKJlViDNyP_2tf6PuHrdG

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT, Please update on my request.

Comment: Could anyone help me out on this please?

Comment: All,Any update on my request ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `polymer-cli` npm package is listed in your dev dependencies (at least it sounds like a dev dependency to me) in your `package.json`. Also make sure you run `npm install` before you run `npm run build`. You might have to point your NPM build script to the Polymer package in your `node_modules` folder because it is not installed globale on the build server

Comment: @ I just included "polymer-build": "^3.0.4", in package.json and added npm task to install before npm build but how to point build script and what is meant by build script here?

Comment: Can you also share polymer dev dependencies to include under package.json file ?

Comment: I think it is `polymer-cli` (https://github.com/Polymer/tools/tree/master/packages/cli) but I'm hoping you know which dependencies you are using. The cli will be installed in `node_modules\polymer-cli` the Polymer CLI tool your build tries to run should be there. So whichever step you have running Polymer should be something like `node_modules\polymer-cli\Polymer` instead. Alternatively, you can install it with `npm install -g polymer-cli`

Comment: Thanks Now Its failing with the error as follows.  611671Z > web-components@ build D:\a\1\s
2018-08-03T12:33:34.2611855Z > polymer build
2018-08-03T12:33:34.2612307Z 
2018-08-03T12:33:37.0180470Z [32minfo[39m: [cli.command.build]    Clearing build\ directory...
2018-08-03T12:33:37.1499629Z [32minfo[39m: [cli.build.build]    (default) Building...
2018-08-03T12:33:38.4086486Z [31merror[39m: [cli.main]   Promise rejection: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\node_modules\highcharts\highstock.js'

Comment: 2018-08-03T12:33:38.4087785Z [31merror[39m: [cli.main]   Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\node_modules\highcharts\highstock.js'
2018-08-03T12:33:38.4344332Z npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2018-08-03T12:33:38.4394282Z npm ERR! errno 1
2018-08-03T12:33:38.4394450Z npm ERR! web-components@ build: `polymer build`
2018-08-03T12:33:38.4394546Z npm ERR! Exit status 1
2018-08-03T12:33:38.4394628Z npm ERR! 
2018-08-03T12:33:38.4394722Z npm ERR! Failed at the web-components@ build script.

Comment: 2018-08-03T12:33:38.4395876Z npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2018-08-03T12:33:38.4611267Z 
2018-08-03T12:33:38.4611795Z npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2018-08-03T12:33:38.4612125Z npm ERR!     C:\npm\cache\_logs\2018-08-03T12_33_38_436Z-debug.log

Comment: it really looks like you are missing dependencies in your `package.json` file. First try to run the same Polymer command locally next make sure everything that is required to build is actually in list as either a dependency or dev dependency in your package.json file. You should be easily able to test this by cloning your repo to a new directory and repeating the steps your build is doing.